# Want to group by items and sum of amount according to items

Tags: group-by, subquery, correlated-subquery

Group by items and sum amount according to items 
I have outer query which selects fields from a temp table how can i get sum of same items here ??
here is query

```
 Select temp.Item,temp.TotalReceivable,temp.Bal  from (
              select (
              (Select SUM(io.TotalAmount) from Inventory_Out io where 
               io.CampusID = cr.CampusID ) - SUM(cr.AmountReceived) Over()) as TotalReceivable,

              (Select ISNULL(SUM(Inventory_Out.TotalAmount),0) - (Select SUM(AmountReceived) from CampusRecovery where CampusRecovery.BillNo = cr.BillNo )
               from Inventory_Out where Inventory_Out.CampusID = cr.CampusID and Inventory_Out.BillNo = cr.BillNo
              )as Bal,

             (Select Item_name from Product where Product.ID = cr.ItemID) as Item

             from CampusRecovery cr

             where 
             cr.CampusID = @CampusID AND  
             cr.RecvDate >= Cast(@StartDate as datetime) AND cr.RecvDate <= Cast(@EndDate as datetime)
            ) as temp
  group by 
  temp.Item,
  temp.TotalReceivable,
  temp.bal
```

Comment: Your formatting is pretty bad.  Could you edit the question so we can clearly see all the subqueries?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yep you are right .. see now it is more clear now i have edited it